# How to decide whether to prepend www. to a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, http, parsing, url, data-cleaning

I'm writing a PHP application where the user can enter a URL and some operations take place afterwards *(further details not relevant to this question)*.

**Requirement:** If the user enters `example.com`, it should be converted to `http://www.example.com`.

The `http://` part is straight-forward but am struggling with the rules that determine whether `www.` is prepended. Since the URL could be anything that might work in a web browser, it could be `localhost` or `192.168.0.1` for example. For these, clearly `www.` shouldn't be prepended.

So the exclusion list from above is: *"If the host is `localhost` or looks like a v4 IP address, don't prepend"*. But expect there will be other cases that need to covered - could anyone advise - or suggest an alternative way of approaching this?

Comment: Suggestion: First try resolving the string as an IP address. If that works, use it. If it doesn't work, then try prepending the `www`, and see if that works. If neither works, you can report an error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rici! Could use a regex to check whether it's an IP address. For the "see if that works" part, am doing this in an isolated part of the code that shouldn't be going to the outside world if you meant to actually try sending a request... But would these checks cover all possible cases?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to send a request, which is problematic. It's sufficient to do domain name resolution, although that is not devoid of problems either; it requires network access, may take some time, and the returned result is not guaranteed to be accurate. So it's a heuristic, not an algorithm, but I don't regard that as an issue because the problem itself has no guaranteed solution. The disadvantages listed above are ameliorated with the use of a DNS cache.

Comment: Technically these are 2 different domains (with and without "www.")

Comment: To explain further - am trying to mimic the behaviour of most web browsers in this respect: If I type `google.com` in to the Chrome address bar, this appears as `https://www.google.com` (after clicking twice to show the full URL). And relative links on the page such as the Google logo (/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) come from [the domain with www.](https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png). Without `www.` prepended, such links [wouldn't work](https://google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png).

Comment: Ahhh think I may have been misunderstanding something. When I type `google.com` into the Chrome address bar it becomes `https://www.google.com` after hitting return. I thought this was something Chrome was doing but having looked more closely, it happens during the page request - there is an HTTP 301 redirect with the new `Location` set in the HTTP header. Thanks for guiding me in this direction @rici - if you'd care to phrase this in an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the user input to IP and decide whether to concatenate the "www" or not.
The user input can be "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:8080","http://127.0.0.1:8080' or "http://exaple.com:8080".

```
$input = ("127.0.0.1:8080");
[$host,$port] = explode(":",trim($input,"http://"));
if(!empty($port)){
}
if (filter_var($host, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    header("location:http://$host:$port");
} else {
    header("location:www.$host:$port");
}
```

Comment: Does this handle `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, localhost will be converted to http://www.localhost/ which still works well.